# OpenCV (-215:Assertion failed) (mtype == CV_8U || mtype == CV_8S) && _mask.sameSize(*psrc1) in function 'cv::binary_op'

Tags: python, opencv, bitwise-operators, bitwise-and

I keep receiving this error when trying to create a mask. The shape, size and type of the mask and 'original' are the same.

The error is on the line:

```py
    img_bitcontour = cv2.bitwise_or(original,original, mask=mask)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.5) C:\ci\opencv-suite_1656607030790\work\modules\core\src\arithm.cpp:230: error: (-215:Assertion failed) (mtype == CV_8U || mtype == CV_8S) && _mask.sameSize(*psrc1) in function 'cv::binary_op'
```

```py
original = cv2.imread(img_path)
background = cv2.imread(background)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(original, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)  #
edges = cv2.Canny(blur, 100, 200)  #
kernel = np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8)
dilation = cv2.dilate(edges, kernel, iterations=6)

ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(dilation, 70, 155, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
ret, thresh_inv = cv2.threshold(dilation, 70, 155, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

# adaptive_thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray, 100, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY,15,2)

#find contours
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
largest_areas = sorted(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
mask = np.zeros(original.shape, np.uint8)
mask = cv2.drawContours(mask, [largest_areas[-1]],0, (255,255,255,255), -1)

print(mask.shape, mask.size, type(mask))
print(original.shape, original.size, type(original))
#
# mask = mask.astype(np.uint8)
# original = original.astype(np.uint8)

img_bitcontour = cv2.bitwise_or(original,original, mask=mask)

mask_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(mask)

background = np.full(background.shape, 255, dtype = np.uint8)
bk = cv2.bitwise_or(background, background, mask=mask_inv)

final = cv2.bitwise_or(img_bitcontour,bk)

titles = ['original image', 'binary', 'binary inverse', 'contours output', 'stack']
images = [gray, thresh, thresh_inv, mask, final]
for i in range(len(images)):
    plt.subplot(2,3,i+1), plt.imshow(images[i],'gray')
    plt.title(titles[i])
    plt.xticks([]),plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
```

Comment: which line of code is giving the error? Could you provide the images?

Comment: Error is on line: img_bitcontour = cv2.bitwise_or(original, original, mask=mask)

Comment: Please show the output of those print statements.

Comment: It expects a single channel image as `mask`. You have fed it with 4 channels. `mask = np.zeros((original.shape[0], original.shape[1]), np.uint8)`; `mask = cv2.drawContours(mask, [largest_areas[-1]],0, 255, -1)`